# How to open Outlook Received and Read Email

Tags: c#, outlook

We are 5 people who are using the same email for responding to our customers by Outlook. I want to come up with a program to open all of the sent emails, read them (*Open them*), find the first person's signature, and add a number to his/her counter so that I can come up with some statistics.

Any ideas on how to open email which outlook received via C# and parse them (*Read*)?

Do you think [this is the correct answer for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880551/how-to-read-emails-from-outlook)?

Please help me.

Comment: It coudl be approximate the right answer however, that connects direct to the web instance of outlook, rather than your local outloo

Comment: Will this be a **one-time statistic** or an **accumulative statistic**? Do you need to manage the stats **ongoing**, or will you re-calculate them **periodically** for a given date range?

Comment: I need to recalculate them periodically, for example weekly.

Comment: @Bugfinder: therefore since we didn't archive the email I can open and analysis them correct?

Comment: @sliverninja: I want to check all the people working properly or no. Right now we dont have any measurement for see who working more and faster then others...

Comment: If you still have the mail yes you can still open them but you wont be able to know who opened them. I dont think. I wrote an app to open and read mails and process them, but I dont think Outlook stores which user marked it as read

Comment: @bugfinder: I want to parse the email, all of us have a specefic signiture, therefore I can find the last person signiture. I mean the person who reply the fix. can u share your code? May I know how I should open sent item mails?

Comment: Sent items are in you sent items folder.. however, signatures arent guarentees, people can remove them etc. My code is too specific for the environment I work in, and I wouldnt be permitted to share due to the fact it handles military data

Comment: @BugFinder: Oh therefore no need :) I will start my coding hopfully by next week, if I had any problem I will update the same post please advise me if any problem I had. Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of examples using mapi and opening outlook and reading mails, or making an addon for outlook

Comment: @BugFinder: I have an issue can you see my post in here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515117/execute-mail-reader-program-without-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633709%28v=exchg.80%29) or [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) to achieve this. It really depends on which route you are more comfortable with. EWS would probably be slower since it has to make remote calls, whereas VSTO would have access to the emails on the local machine. Either route should give you access to the **Email Body**.

**VSTO**: [MailItem.Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.body.aspx) 
**EWS**: [EmailMessage.Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.item.body%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja, I will mark you by next week after I start my coding but I think it will useful.

Comment: @SilverNinja: I have an issue would you mind check my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515117/execute-mail-reader-program-without-visual-studio