# Execute mail reader program without visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, outlook

With reference to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098549/how-to-open-outlook-received-and-read-email), I already wrote my program and it is working awesome when I am using VS2008 for run it.

I have two more questions:

**1.** I want to check with you guys when I run my program all the mail are appearing in VS output as xml file, ***but I never used to print them in output.*** is it usual for all or I need to add something to remove it. I feel it takes long time from my PC to show mails in output.

**2.** my second question is that when I want to use only exe file stand alone(run program via exe file not with VS ) I am receiving below error and program is hanging & close.

> "MailReader has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are
>   sorry for the inconvenience."

As I mentioned above this program is working fine in VS.

I copy part of my code that read mails and split them for your reference.

```
public void ReadMail()
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender,
                                                                                X509Certificate certificate,
                                                                          X509Chain chain,
                                                                                SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
            try
            {
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
                service.TraceEnabled = true;
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_username, _password); //Modify this
                service.Url = new Uri(_exchange); //Modify this
                service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

                service.Url = new Uri(_exchange);
                service.TraceEnabled = true;
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(_username, _password); //Modify this
                service.Url = new Uri(_exchange);
                //SearchFilter to get unreaded messages only.
                SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
                ItemView itemview = new ItemView(Int16.MaxValue);


                //DateTime searchdate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 6); //Year, month, day
                SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, Convert.ToDateTime(startDate));
                SearchFilter lessthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeSent,Convert.ToDateTime(finishDate));
                SearchFilter[] f = { greaterthanfilter, lessthanfilter };
                SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, f);
                //Folder folder = Folder.Bind(this.m_Service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot); //Or the folder you want to search in
                //FindItemsResults<Item> results = folder.FindItems(filter, new ItemView(1000));


                FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems,filter, itemview);

                Action action = () => fr.setText(findResults.Items.Count + "mails need to analysis from "+startDate +" to "+ finishDate);
                fr.Invoke(action, null);

                action = () => fr.setMaximumProgressBar(findResults.Items.Count);
                fr.Invoke(action, null);

                dmd = new List<DailyMailDetails>();

                foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
                {
                    string messageDate = "Error in Date";
                    string messageSubj = "Error in Subject";
                    int index = 0; 
                    try
                    {
                        PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.DateTimeSent, ItemSchema.Body, ItemSchema.Subject);
                        propertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
                        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, propertySet);

                        string temp = startSign.ToUpper();
                        int start = message.Body.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(temp) + temp.Length;
                        int end = message.Body.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(finishSign.ToUpper());
                        int len = end - start;
                        string text = message.Body.Text.Substring(start, len);

                        index = findDmdIndex(message.DateTimeSent.ToShortDateString().ToString());

                        if (index == -1)
                        {
                            dmd.Add(new DailyMailDetails(message.DateTimeSent.ToShortDateString().ToString(), (List<PeopleSigniture>)Extensions.Clone<PeopleSigniture>(OrginallistPeopleSign)));
                            index = dmd.Count - 1;
                        }
                        bool signExist = false;

                        for (int i = 0; i < listPeopleSign.Count; i++)
                            if (text.ToUpper().Contains(dmd[index].peopleSign[i].Signiture.ToUpper()))
                            {
                                dmd[index].peopleSign[i].addResponse(message.DateTimeSent.ToString(), message.Subject.ToString());
                                signExist = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        messageDate = message.DateTimeSent.ToString();
                        messageSubj = message.Subject.ToString();
                        if (!signExist)
                            dmd[index].peopleSign[dmd[index].peopleSign.Count - 2].addResponse(message.DateTimeSent.ToString(), message.Subject.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        dmd[index].peopleSign[dmd[index].peopleSign.Count - 1].addResponse(messageDate, messageSubj);
                    }


                    action = () => fr.increasePrograss();
                    fr.Invoke(action, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Class: Mail Function:ReadMail" + ex.Message);
            }
            Action action2 = () => fr.setText(ToString(true),dmd);
            fr.Invoke(action2, null);
        }
```

Comment: Any idea? I am still suffering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For issue #1 - you are viewing the XML output likely because you [have EWS tracing enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633655%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). You need to set [`ExchangeService.TraceEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservicebase.traceenabled%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) to `false` or comment it out entirely. (*You also have many duplicate lines of code you need to cleanup.*)

```
service.TraceEnabled = false;
```

For issue #2 - you need to determine the actual .NET exception. Without this - we cannot help you further. It could be crashing for countless reasons. Please provide a stack trace.